# TypeError: cyclical structure in JSON object, js engine: hermes

Tags: json, react-native

[image]

TypeError: cyclical structure in JSON object, js engine: hermes

when the input text is null it works but when its !empty this error comes

Comment: Please add your code as text to your post - images of code aren't allowed (see [ask]).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you assign the TextInput's onChange property to your state setter. onChange receives an event, which is a large, cyclical structure that contains information you don't need here.

The easiest way is to use onChangeText instead. onChangeText is called only with the text of the input.

```js
  <TextInput
    // onChange={setMobile}
    // is equivalent to
    // onChange={event => seMobile(event)}
    // instead use
    onChangeText={setMobile}
    // ...
```